# What is the point of a “sealed interface” in Java?

Tags: java, interface, sealed-class, java-15, java-sealed-type

*Sealed classes* and *sealed interfaces* were a [preview feature in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360), with a [second preview in Java 16](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397), and now [proposed delivery in Java 17](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409).

They have provided classic examples like `Shape` -> `Circle`, `Rectangle`, etc.

I understand sealed *classes*: the `switch` statement example provided makes sense to me. But, sealed *interfaces* are a mystery to me. Any class implementing an interface is forced to provide definitions for them. Interfaces don't compromise the integrity of the implementation because the interface is stateless on its own. Doesn't matter whether I wanted to limit implementation to a few selected classes.

Could you tell me the proper use case of sealed interfaces in Java 15+?

Comment: There are many nice blog posts for example this [post](https://medium.com/better-programming/java-15-features-sealed-and-hidden-classes-pattern-matching-and-text-blocks-38f4efdc8adc).

Comment: Sealed interface allows you to control which code is responsible for implementing it. Its mean that you can use pattern matching in more safe way, because you will know that all inherited classes have some restrict. The term 'sealed' is very known in Scala, the JVM language.

Comment: What do you mean by, "_Interfaces don't compromise the integrity of the implementation..._"? Compromised integrity is bad, so this sounds like a positive feature of interfaces.

Comment: @jaco0646 Extending a class can compromise its integrity because it contains a certain state. Extending an interface only adds operations and does not affect the integrity of the implementation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict inheritance to a single subclass in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784466/how-to-restrict-inheritance-to-a-single-subclass-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although interfaces have no state themselves, they have access to state, eg via getters, and may have code that does something with that state via `default` methods.

Therefore the reasoning supporting `sealed` for classes may also be applied to interfaces.

Comment: I believe the key here might be the `default` methods since they are the ones that are unavoidably inherited by all its implementations?

Answer (score 15):

Basically to give a sealed hierarchy when there is no concrete state to share across the different members. That's the major difference between implementing an interface and extending a class - interfaces don't have fields or constructors of their own.

But in a way, that isn't the important question. The real issue is why you would want a sealed hierarchy to begin with. Once that is established it should be clearer where sealed interfaces fit in.

(apologies in advance for the contrived-ness of examples and the long winded-ness)

### 1. To use subclassing without "designing for subclassing".

Lets say you have a class like this, and it is in a library you already published.

```java
public final class Airport {
    private List<String> peopleBooked;

    public Airport() {
        this.peopleBooked = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        this.peopleBooked.add(name);
    }

    public void bookPeople(String... names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            this.bookPerson(name);
        }
    }

    public int peopleBooked() {
        return this.peopleBooked.size();
    }
}
```

Now, you want to add a new version to your library that will print out the names of people booked as they are booked. There are several possible paths to do this.

If you were designing from scratch, you could reasonably replace the `Airport` class with  an `Airport` interface and design the `PrintingAirport` to compose with a `BasicAirport` like so.

```java
public interface Airport {
    void bookPerson(String name);

    void bookPeople(String... names);

    int peopleBooked();
}
```

```java
public final class BasicAirport implements Airport {
    private final List<String> peopleBooked;

    public Airport() {
        this.peopleBooked = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        this.peopleBooked.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void bookPeople(String... names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            this.bookPerson(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int peopleBooked() {
        return this.peopleBooked.size();
    }
}
```

```java
public final class PrintingAirport implements Airport {
    private final Airport delegateTo;

    public PrintingAirport(Airport delegateTo) {
        this.delegateTo = delegateTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
        this.delegateTo.bookPerson(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void bookPeople(String... names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        this.delegateTo.bookPeople(names);
    }

    @Override
    public int peopleBooked() {
        return this.peopleBooked.size();
    }
}
```

This isn't doable in our hypothetical though because the `Airport` class already exists. There are going to be calls to `new Airport()` and methods that expect something of type `Airport` specifically that can't be kept in a backwards compatible way unless we use inheritance.

So to do that pre-java 15 you would remove the `final` from your class and write the subclass.

```java
public class Airport {
    private List<String> peopleBooked;

    public Airport() {
        this.peopleBooked = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        this.peopleBooked.add(name);
    }

    public void bookPeople(String... names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            this.bookPerson(name);
        }
    }

    public int peopleBooked() {
        return this.peopleBooked.size();
    }
}
```

```java
public final class PrintingAirport extends Airport {
    @Override
    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
        super.bookPerson(name);
    }
}
```

At which point we run into one of the most basic issues with inheritance - there are tons of ways to "break encapsulation". Because the `bookPeople` method in `Airport` happens to call `this.bookPerson` internally, our `PrintingAirport` class works as designed, because its new `bookPerson` method will end up being called once for every person.

But if the `Airport` class were changed to this,

```java
public class Airport {
    private List<String> peopleBooked;

    public Airport() {
        this.peopleBooked = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void bookPerson(String name) {
        this.peopleBooked.add(name);
    }

    public void bookPeople(String... names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            this.peopleBooked.add(name);
        }
    }

    public int peopleBooked() {
        return this.peopleBooked.size();
    }
}
```

then the `PrintingAirport` subclass won't behave correctly unless it also overrided `bookPeople`. Make the reverse change and it won't behave correctly unless it didn't override `bookPeople`.

This isn't the end of the world or anything, its just something that needs to be considered and documented - "how do you extend this class and what are you allowed to override", but when you have a public class open to extension **anyone** can extend it.

If you skip documenting how to subclass or don't document enough its easy to end up in a situation where code you don't control that uses your library or module can depend on a small detail of a superclass that you are now stuck with.

Sealed classes let you side step this by opening your superclass up to extension only for the classes you want to.

```java
public sealed class Airport permits PrintingAirport {
    // ...
}
```

And now you don't need to document anything to outside consumers, just yourself.

So how do interfaces fit in to this? Well, lets say you did think ahead and you have the system where you are adding features via composition.

```java
public interface Airport {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public final class BasicAirport implements Airport {
   // ...
}
```

```java
public final class PrintingAirport implements Airport {
    // ...
}
```

You might not be sure that you **don't** want to use inheritance later to save some duplication between the classes, but because your Airport interface is public you would need to make some intermediate `abstract class` or something similar.

You can be defensive and say "you know what, until I have a better idea of where I want this API to go I am going to be the only one able to make implementations of the interface".

```java
public sealed interface Airport permits BasicAirport, PrintingAirport {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public final class BasicAirport implements Airport {
   // ...
}
```

```java
public final class PrintingAirport implements Airport {
    // ...
}
```

### 2. To represent data "cases" that have different shapes.

Lets say you send a request to a web service and it is going to return one of two things in JSON.

```json
{
    "color": "red",
    "scaryness": 10,
    "boldness": 5
}
```

```json
{
    "color": "blue",
    "favorite_god": "Poseidon"
}
```

Somewhat contrived, sure, but you can easily imagine a "type" field or similar that distinguishes what other fields will be present.

Because this is Java, we are going to want to map the raw untyped JSON representation into classes. Lets play out this situation.

One way is to have one class that contains all the possible fields and just have some be `null` depending.

```java
public enum SillyColor {
    RED, BLUE
}
```

```java
public final class SillyResponse {
    private final SillyColor color;
    private final Integer scaryness;
    private final Integer boldness;
    private final String favoriteGod;

    private SillyResponse(
        SillyColor color,
        Integer scaryness,
        Integer boldness,
        String favoriteGod
    ) {
        this.color = color;
        this.scaryness = scaryness;
        this.boldness = boldness;
        this.favoriteGod = favoriteGod;
    }

    public static SillyResponse red(int scaryness, int boldness) {
        return new SillyResponse(SillyColor.RED, scaryness, boldness, null);
    }

    public static SillyResponse blue(String favoriteGod) {
        return new SillyResponse(SillyColor.BLUE, null, null, favoriteGod);
    }

    // accessors, toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

While this technically works in that it does contain all the data, there isn't all that much gained in terms of type-level safety. Any code that gets a `SillyResponse` needs to know to check the `color` itself before accessing any other properties of the object and it needs to know which ones are safe to get.

We can at least make the `color` an enum instead of a string so that code shouldn't need to handle any other colors, but its still far less than ideal. It gets even worse the more complicated or more numerous the different cases become.

What we ideally want to do is have some common supertype to all the cases that you can switch on.

Because its no longer going to be needed to switch on, the `color` property won't be strictly necessary but depending on personal taste you can keep that as something accessible on the interface.

```java
public interface SillyResponse {
    SillyColor color();
}
```

Now the two subclasses will have different sets of methods, and code that gets either one can use `instanceof` to figure out which they have.

```java
public final class Red implements SillyResponse {
    private final int scaryness;
    private final int boldness;

    @Override
    public SillyColor color() {
        return SillyColor.RED;
    }

    // constructor, accessors, toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

```java
public final class Blue implements SillyResponse {
    private final String favoriteGod;

    @Override
    public SillyColor color() {
        return SillyColor.BLUE;
    }

    // constructor, accessors, toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

The issue is that, because `SillyResponse` is a public interface, anyone can implement it and `Red` and `Blue` aren't necessarily the only subclasses that can exist.

```java
if (resp instanceof Red) {
    // ... access things only on red ...
}
else if (resp instanceof Blue) {
    // ... access things only on blue ...
}
else {
    throw new RuntimeException("oh no");
}
```

Which means this "oh no" case can always happen.

An aside: Before java 15 to remedy this people used the ["type safe visitor" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). I recommend not learning that for your sanity, but if you are curious you can look at code [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) generates - its all a large hierarchy of differently "shaped" data structures.

Sealed classes let you say "hey, these are the only cases that matter."

```java
public sealed interface SillyResponse permits Red, Blue {
    SillyColor color();
}
```

And even if the cases share zero methods, the interface can function just as well as a "marker type", and still give you a type to write when you expect one of the cases.

```java
public sealed interface SillyResponse permits Red, Blue {
}
```

At which point you might start to see the resemblance to enums.

```java
public enum Color { Red, Blue }
```

enums say "these two instances are the only two possibilities." They can have some methods and fields to them.

```java
public enum Color { 
    Red("red"), 
    Blue("blue");

    private final String name;

    private Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

But all instances need to have the *same* methods and the *same* fields and those values need to be constants. In a sealed hierarchy you get the same "these are the only two cases" guarantee, but the different cases can have non-constant data and different data from each other - if that makes sense.

The whole pattern of "sealed interface + 2 or more record classes" is fairly close to what is intended by constructs like rust's enums.

This also applies equally to general objects that have different "shapes" of behaviors, but they don't get their own bullet point.

### 3. To force an invariant

There are some invariants, like immutability, that are impossible to guarantee if you allow subclasses.

```java
// All apples should be immutable!
public interface Apple {
    String color();
}
```

```java
public class GrannySmith implements Apple {
    public String color; // granny, no!

    public String color() {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

And those invariants might be relied upon later on in the code, like when giving an object to another thread or similar. Making the hierarchy sealed means you can document and guarantee stronger invariants than if you allowed arbitrary subclassing.

### To cap off

Sealed interfaces more or less serve the same purpose as sealed classes, you just only use concrete inheritance when you want to share implementation between classes that goes beyond what something like default methods can give.

Comment: I still fail to see the point in having this feature.

Comment: @AminM I know its been a bit, but if you give more details about your thought process I can maybe answer it better for you.

Comment: As someone that has developed in Java since the beginning it just seems like they are adding features to keep up with the Joneses. Adding more language features is not always a good thing. It just adds bloat and reduces the quality of the language.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you write an authentication library, containing an interface for password encoding, ie `char[] encryptPassword(char[] pw)`. Your library provides a couple of implementations the user can choose from.

You don't want him to be able to pass in his own implementation that might be insecure.

Answer (score 4):

> Could you tell me the proper use case of sealed interfaces in Java
> 15+?

I wrote some experimental code and a supporting [blog](https://donraab.medium.com/immutable-collections-in-java-using-sealed-types-ae8eb580fc1e?source=friends_link&sk=e9b062d5b59c0d341b718c32150e2d26) to illustrate how sealed interfaces could be used to implement an `ImmutableCollection` interface hierarchy for Java that provides *contractual*, *structural* and *verifiable* immutability. I think this could be a practical use case for sealed interfaces.

The example includes four `sealed` interfaces: `ImmutableCollection`, `ImmutableSet`, `ImmutableList` and `ImmutableBag`. `ImmutableCollection` is extended by `ImmutableList/Set/Bag`. Each of the leaf interfaces `permits` two final concrete implementations. This blog describes the design goal of restricting the interfaces so developers cannot implement "Immutable" interfaces and provide implementations that are mutable.

Note: I am a committer for [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 2):

Since Java introduced *records* in version 14, one use case for sealed interfaces will certainly be to create sealed records. This is not possible with sealed classes, because records cannot extend a class (much like enums).

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are not always entirely defined by their API alone. Take, for example [`ProtocolFamily`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ProtocolFamily.html). This interface would be easy to implement, considering its methods, but the result would not be useful regarding the intended semantics, as [all methods accepting `ProtocolFamily` as input](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/class-use/ProtocolFamily.html) would just throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, in the best case.

This is a typical example for an interface that would be sealed if that feature existed in earlier versions; the interface is intended to abstract the implementations exported by a library, but not to have implementations outside that library.

The newer type [`ConstantDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/ConstantDesc.html) mentions that intention even explicitly:

> Non-platform classes should not implement [`ConstantDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/ConstantDesc.html) directly. Instead, they should extend [`DynamicConstantDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/DynamicConstantDesc.html)…

> #### API Note:
>
> In the future, if the Java language permits, [`ConstantDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/constant/ConstantDesc.html) may become a sealed interface, which would prohibit subclassing except by explicitly permitted types.

Regarding possible use cases, there is no difference between a sealed abstract class and a sealed interface, but the sealed interface still allows implementors extending different classes (within the limits set by the author). Or being implemented by `enum` types.

In short, sometimes, interfaces are used to have the least coupling between a library and its clients, without the intention of having client-side implementations of it.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Before java 15 developers used to think in a way that code reusability is the goal. But it's not true to all extents, in some cases we want wide accessibility but not extensibility for better security and also codebase management.

This feature is about enabling more fine-grained inheritance control in Java. Sealing allows classes and interfaces to define their permitted subtypes.

The sealed interface allows us to enable it to reason clearly all the classes that can implement it.