# How to restrict inheritance to a single subclass in Java

Tags: java

Suppose there is class `A` which is parent class and class `B` that extends `A`.

Now I should not allow to extend class `A` to class `C` (`class C extends A`), or any other class.

How to do that?

Comment: We could achieve what we want with [Sealed classes (link to Baeldung)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sealed-classes-interfaces).

Comment: Use Scala or Kotlin or, frankly, any other JVM language. At this point, I think Java's just slowly copying features from all of them, on a ten-year delay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point of "final class" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/what-is-the-point-of-final-class-in-java)

Comment: final class A - works with java 6+, also you can use `protected` modifier (`extension` and `visability` will work with classes in the same package only )

Comment: @user16320675 There was anser in the bottom. (Java 17) But in fact parent shouldn't know anything about children. It means something wrong with structure/logic. I would recommend use protected modifier + do classes structure research.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's why Java 17 has sealed classes. This feature was added as a preview feature in Java 15.

> [Sealed classes and interfaces restrict which other classes or
> interfaces may extend or implement them.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409)

In your case you can do the following:-

```
public sealed class A permits B {

}

public class B extends A{ //No error

}

public class C extends A{  //error because class C is not permitted 

}
```

#### The [Goals](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409) of Sealed classes in java are :-

- Allow the author of a class or interface to control which code is responsible for implementing it.
- Provide a more declarative way than access modifiers to restrict the use of a superclass.
- Support future directions in pattern matching by providing a foundation for the exhaustive analysis of patterns.

---

IF you want a class not extendable, then you can use `final`.

```
public final class A{ //Cannot be extended by other classes.
}
```

##### Helpful links:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409

https://www.baeldung.com/java-sealed-classes-interfaces

[What are sealed classes in Java 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218585/what-are-sealed-classes-in-java-17)

Comment: Will this possible in java 8 or 11 ?

Comment: No they're new in 15.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an older version of Java, the natural solution is simply to make class `A` package-private. This prevents classes outside of the package from subclassing `A` directly.

If `A` itself does need to be exposed publicly, there is still a solution: declare another class `PublicA` which is public and final, where `PublicA` is a subclass of `A` with no additional or overridden members. Then classes in other packages can use `PublicA` instead of `A`, but they cannot subclass it.

The only other practical difference between `PublicA` and `A` is that the class `B` is a subclass of `A` but not a subclass of `PublicA`; so for example `obj instanceof PublicA` won't work to detect instances of `B` or other public subclasses of `A`. If an `instanceof` check like this might be required in other packages, then either a public interface can be exposed which `A` implements, or `PublicA` can expose a static method which returns `arg instanceof A` from inside the package, where it is allowed.

Answer (score -1):

From Java 15 onward such use-case can be implemented by using **sealed modifier** and **permits clause**

**The restriction of a class or interface to become a parent for a specific class or interface.**
Following are **two use case** one for **class** and another for **interface**.

**1. Using Class:** Suppose we have an class ClazzA, we want to restrict this class to extend only by class ClazzB. That is **no any other class can extends  ClazzA except ClazzB.**

```
public abstract sealed class ClazzA permits ClazzB {

    final String str;
    
    public ClazzA(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void method() {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

**2.  Using Interface:** Suppose we have an interface InterfaceA, we want to restrict this interface to extend only by interface InterfaceB.
That is **no any other interface can extends except InterfaceB**

```
public sealed interface InterfaceA permits InterfaceB {

    int method1();

    default int defaultMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```